# How to modify the value of a Hashmap, which has key&value as Strings,and the 'value' is a single string consisting of comma separated values

Tags: string, hashmap, java-7, stringbuffer

I am trying to modify a Hashmap .
The 'value' is a single string consisting of comma separated values.
(for e.g.: "aid=abc,bid=def,cid=gh2")

I need to replace particular values from them with a corresponding value from the DB.
(for e.g. changing the bid to 123, which would result in the above 'value' string as: "aid=abc,bid=123,cid=gh2")

And then set the modified 'value' to the corresponding key, so that the hashmap consists of modified values.

I tried to iterate through the keys , and with map(key) which will give the value, I tried to convert that to a list of comma separated values and then iterate through that list, and in each of the string, if I find 'bid'(example string above), then I do the necessary manipulation and then set it back to the Hashmap(which I Wasnt able to do since Strings arent mutable)

for (String name :outputMap.keySet())
List urlList = Arrays.asList(outputMap.get(name).split(","));     for(int i=0;i

expected result:"aid=abc,bid=123,cid=gh2" (post the manipulation)
actual result: unable to do.

I have used Stringbuffer for issues where string had to be modified, but was a little apprehensive to use that here, since this has already multiple conversions going.

The code needs to Java 7 compliant, since this is being deployed in a Client machine still using some legacy environment.(They are scheduled to migrate to java 8 , but thats scheduled for much later)
Any assistance here would be appreciated.

Comment: *actual result: unable to do.* what is this suppose to mean?

Comment: It is supposed to mean , I am unable to do the manipulation mentioned, since I am trying to modify a String, which isnt allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
static Map<String, String> replace(Map<String, String> map, String toReplace, String replacement) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, 
                       e -> transformValue(e.getValue(), toReplace, replacement)));
}

static String transformValue(String value, String toReplace, String replacement) {
    return Arrays.stream(value.split(","))
            .map(pair -> pair.split("="))
            .map(sPair -> sPair[0] + "=" + (toReplace.equals(sPair[0]) ? replacement : sPair[1]))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

this will iterate through all entries of map and create a new map with changed values. Example:

```
var map = Map.of("key1", "aid=abc,bid=def,cid=gh2");
System.out.println(replace(map, "bid", "123").get("key1"));
```

will print `aid=abc,bid=123,cid=gh2`

Comment: you could have used `Pattern::splitAsStream` instead of `value::split`. And you might say that for a single character, `String::split` will cache the Pattern, but that is an undocumented feature...

Comment: @Adiran: Thank you for the solution,but one limitation is that only java 1.7 is being allowed in the Target client machine, since its still legacy.. (They are in the process of migrating to 1.8, but thats scheduled for later). Will update this in the main question as well, I had missed to do it earlier.                                                    If you can please suggest something similar or even edit the above to make it 1,7 compliant, it would be very nice

Comment: @SidTechs1 it would have been very nice if you tagged your question from _the start_ with java-7. This answer invested some valuable time in it...